# Semi-transparent jquery menu

Tags: jquery

Can anybody suggest some nice semi-transparent menu for jQuery? I googled up but didn't find any such menu.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, making an element semi-transparent is as easy as `.css('opacity', x)`, where x is a number between 0 and 1. Of course, if you are talking about a menu that fades in and out, keep in mind that jQuery does provide [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) functions.